# Создание аффинного преобразования при стабилизации видео

Tags: c#, изображения, opencv, видео, emgucv

При создании аффинного преобразования для картинок, чтобы их стабилизировать столкнулся с проблемой, что после преобразования получается какая-то каша
типо такого:
[image: Каша]
хотя при выборе точек, по которым производится преобразование все выглядит вполне адекватно

Предыдущий кадр:

[image: Предыдущий кадр]

Кадр который стабилизируется:

[image: Кадр который стабилизируется]

Всю работу выполняю при помощи библиотеки Emgu Cv

Так создается матрица для аффинного преобразования:

```
private Mat GetAffineTransform(PairOfPoints[] pairs)
        {
            var src = new PointF[pairs.Length];
            var dest = new PointF[pairs.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++)
            {
                src[i] = pairs[i].p1;
                dest[i] = pairs[i].p2;
            }
            return CvInvoke.GetAffineTransform(src, dest);
        }
```

Так производится аффинное преобразование:

```
using (var bmp = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Bitmaps[i + 1]))
                using (var abmp = bmp.WarpAffine(GetAffineTransform(Pairs[i].ToList().Where((x) => x.Chosen).ToList().GetRange(0, 3).ToArray()), Inter.Cubic,
                    Warp.FillOutliers, BorderType.Constant, new Bgr(0, 0, 0)))
                {
                    res[i + 1] = abmp.ToBitmap();
                }
```

Массив `Pairs[i]` отсортирован по расстоянию между парами точек на текущем и следующем кадре (то есть аффинное преобразование делается по трем точкам расстояние между которыми наименьшее)

А свойство `PairOfPoints.Chosen` указывает на то, что точки находятся на переднем плане и по ним стоит стабилизировать.

Может у кого-нибудь есть идеи или советы как сделать адекватное аффинное преобразование.

Comment: Случайно не для буллет-тайма стабилизацией занимаетесь?

Comment: @МихаилТатаринцев, для него, уже сделал